# Bat file that opens a powershell file how to get the right directory?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Have made a  bat file thats  point to  a  powershell  and open this my problem is i need it on severel Computers and cant change every time the Script Path

what i made is  this

```
cd %USERPROFILE%\Downloads\Pytho\Brd\ & REM cdinto the folder of update bat file
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\Pytho\Brd\updatebrewdall.ps1'"
```

this is  working  but i cant change  path  in every  machines so is  there a automatic solution of it??

i start this  with task Schedule to let Task Schedule  know were the file  is  i  put in  the  cd comment

i  cant open via arguments i need to open it in the real folder to let the update file find the rest  needed files

Answer (score 0):

some gave  me advice i think this is better

```
pushd "%~dp0"
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File updatebrewdall.ps1
popd
```